# How to use Siteseeker with EPiServer post version 9?

Tags: c#, episerver

I'm working on a EPiServer WebForms project which has been updated from EPiServer version 8.8 to version 11.17.

I've solved most of the breaking changes but now I've hit a problem regarding the sites search engine, Siteseeker.

It seems Siteseeker is dependant on Unified files from the EPiServer.Web.Hosting assembly. 
However unified files are no longer supported after EPiServer v9(read under "Virtual Path Providers (Unified File System)").
https://world.episerver.com/documentation/upgrading/Episerver-CMS/9/Breaking-changes/#virtual

My Exception:

- Exception Details: EPiServer.Framework.Initialization.InitializationException: While loading .NET types from "SiteSeeker.EPiServer" the following error(s) was reported:
- System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'EPiServer.Web.Hosting.UnifiedFile' from assembly 'EPiServer, Version=11.11.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxdea738b45b7'.

My question is basically: Is there any way to use siteseeker post EPiServer v9?

This is my first time posting a question so if I'm missing something crucial please ask and I'll try to provide as good an answer as I can, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should contact the creators of siteseeker directly to check if they have any packages available for you to use with post Episerver 9 versions. Their site is located here: http://www.siteseeker.se/en/